# Как удалить все слова в строке после первого слова?

Tags: javascript

Пожалуйста, подскажите как должно выглядеть выражение на JS для того, чтобы удалить все слова после первого слова?

Например: "Вася Иванович Пупкин". Надо получить просто "Вася"
Слова всегда разные...

Comment: Можно найти положение первого пробела в строке через `indexOf(' ')` и удалить, начиная с него. Можно превратить строку в массив, разбив её по пробелу `split(' ')` – и взять нулевой элемент массива. Можно регулярным выражением поймать только первое слово через `preg_match()`. Попробуйте найти документацию с примерами по этим методам и напишите хоть какой-то код.

Comment: а что Вы **уже** попробовали сделать? как сами попытались решить задачу?

Comment: А можно не примере с переменной? Там х = "слова слова" как дальше?

Comment: p.s. вместо `preg_match()` разумеется, имелся в виду [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не обязательно что-то вырезать. Можно через разделитель работать, и брать его первый элемент

```
var str = 'Вася Иванович Пупкин'
console.log(str.split(' ')[0]);
```

Comment: это есть в первом комментарии к вопросу. Жаль, что ТС просто скопирует ваш ответ, а сам и дальше будет прибегать на SO за готовым решением, пока дают.

Comment: @Sergiks, не могу не согласится с тобой. И извини, я что-то пропустил твой коммент. Просто увидел вопрос, написал ответ. Но, да. Люди нынче не очень любят читать доки, о языках на котором хотят писать.